Getting error while retrieving vmware hostname and uuid
I have a terraform file which is making a module call to terraform templates to provision a server in vmware as below :
I am trying to get the list of hostnames in local block to pass to cert genration logic.
locals {
  rs_hostnames   = tolist(flatten(module.er[*].name))
  rs_instance_ids = tolist(flatten(module.er[*].uuid))
}

module "er" {
  source  = "git::https://abc/repo?branch"
  vms = var.kl //list of hostnames and ip addresses 
}

variables.tf:
--------------
variable "kl" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string
    vm_ip = string
  }))
}


Getting error message for module.er[*].name
This object does not have attribute called "name" or "uuid"

Did you define the module outputs which have names name and uuid?

please provide the code of "git::https://abc/repo?branch"

If you can not provide the code do output "test" { value = module.er } and add that to your question so others can see what the output structure looks like on that

Thanks @MarkoE and Helder for bringing this to my attention. I did not have output for hostnames in base module , fixed that and now it is all good. Thank you
